# Cannot reset MySQL default root password after initial installation

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat, password-recovery

I have installed mysql 5.7 on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.5 server and when I tried to run following command after installation it is asking for a password for root@localhost.

```
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

I have never set a root password and I'm logged in to Linux as root user.

Then I have found following documentation for resetting root password and followed that one too.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html

But even after starting the server with following command it is asking for a password

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start --skip-grant-tables &
```

I have tried starting the server with `init-file` option, but no success.

Does anyone know how to reset the password correctly or default MySQL password?

Comment: See the section [Recover MySQL root password](https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords). I used it yesterday on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Restart the service without authentication

### Ubuntu/Debian

```
service mysql stop
service mysql start --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

### Other sysv

If you're on a `sysv` Linux use this

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
/etc/init.d/mysqld start --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

## Resetting

Then you need to login as `root`

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then when logged in run

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

## Difference between other guides

There are a lot of "guides" on this, for clarity,

- Some guides use the older `SET PASSWORD` syntax, that's pre 5-7.6, don't use that anymore.
- Some guides just don't use `--skip-networking`, that's unsafe.
- Some guides don't connect with the `-u root` that's more error-prone.

Comment: This gives the error: `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, if you want a full clean installation. Resets accounts, too.

```sh
sudo apt purge mariadb-server && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ && sudo apt install mariadb-server && sudo systemctl stop mariadb && sudo mysql_install_db && sudo systemctl stop mysql && sudo systemctl start mariadb && sudo systemctl enable mariadb
```