# Unable to connect to sql server on Ubuntu after MySQLAlchemy connection

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

**Context:**
I have installed mysql-server on Ubuntu and was able to setup password for root account and also created a few accounts with all privileges. I was able to connect to any user or the root user using the usual

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

I enter my password and I connect to the databases.

**Issue:**
I have a python flask application that uses SQLAlchemy to connect to the database using a username that I created, with a password. That user has all privileges. After I ran my application, I am UNABLE to connect to any user account from the terminal but the SQLAlchemy connection works fine via the flask application.

**Fixes tried**

- I tried restarting the mysql service.
- Turned off the flask application.
- I tried restarting the linux host.

I need to fix this issue and be able to connect to the mysql database from terminal as well as from the application (currently only application connects to the database).

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot reset MySQL default root password after initial installation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193854/cannot-reset-mysql-default-root-password-after-initial-installation)

Comment: After spending a few hours myself figured out that the issue is with users that had '@', in the password. For whatever reason the SQLAlchemy python library does not like that char in password so I created a new user without '@' in the password and that helped me connect with my python app.

After that connection, all user passwords with @ in it refused to work, but the users without @ in the password still work just fine. Apparently SQLAlchemy messed up passwords for those accounts. Luckily I had this backup account that I created without @ which I will use to reset other account passwords.